# can i attach css to email newsletter HTML file

Tags: css, email, templates, newsletter

I am trying to make an html news letter (email template). Can I attach a CSS file to this template? Will it work properly?

Comment: I think you need to add all the styles inline.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

No you can add only on inline css like

`<div style="color:#000">Hello</div>`

Answer (score 0):

look like this sample

```
<html>
 <head>
<title> 
 <!--mohammad reza ashouri :megacoder999@gmail.com -->
</title>
<style> 
<!--
p { color:#009900; 
font-family:"comic sans ms",sans-serif; }
h1 { color:#660000; font-size:12pt; }
-->
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>    email template </h1>
<p>I am a very basic emaol template.</p>
  ......
</body>
</html>
```